# Pagination using PDO with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, pdo

I have some problems with the pagination. I executed the query directly on my database console and works fine..

```
public function method($arg, $db)//$db is a PDO connection link
{
    try
    {
        $next = $arg * 9;
        $top = 9;
        $sql = "SELECT col01, col02, col03 ";
        $sql .= "FROM table ";
        $sql .= "ORDER BY col01 ASC ";
        $sql .= ($next === 0)? "LIMIT ".$top : "LIMIT ".$next.", ".$top;    
        $return = $db->prepare($sql);
        $return->execute();

        $return->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->minis = $return->fetch();
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOExcepction $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you echo $sql after the last concatenation... what is printed?

Comment: That was the first thing I've done to test the query getting the result: SELECT col01, col02, col03 FROM table ORDER BY col01 ASC LIMIT 9 (editing it to the values of the example; it was tested with $arg=0)

Comment: In fact, I copied the exact query created by the script and paste it into the mysql console and executed it.. Works great! But when testing on browser is only showing the first row

Comment: You should mention the *problem* in the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only returning the first row because you only call `fetch()` once. Call it in a loop and accumulate the results into an array:

```
while ($row = $return->fetch()) {
  // Append the current row onto your array
  $this->minis[] = $row;
}
return true;
```

Comment: FetchAll

no need of while loop in pdo.

Comment: Yes, but the given array has more values than necessary sometimes

Answer (score 1):

> `PDOStatement::fetch` — Fetches ***the next row*** from a result set
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

You are only returning *the first result* with your single call to `fetch()`. You need to call `fetch` until there are no more results. Read the examples in the manual again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->minis = $return->fetchAll();
```

it'l return all the data in a multi dimensional array.